# What does the rpart "Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character' " message mean?

Tags: r, rpart, cart-analysis

I've been banging my head against `rpart` for a few days now (trying to make classification trees for this dataset that I have), and I think it's time to ask a lifeline at this point :-)  I'm sure it's something silly that I'm not seeing, but here's what I've been doing:

```
EuropeWater <- read.csv(file=paste("/Users/artessaniccola/Documents/",
                       "Magic Briefcase/CityTypology/Europe_water.csv",sep=""))
library(rpart)
attach(EuropeWater)
names(EuropeWater)
[1] "City"          "waterpercapita_m3" "water_class"       "population"       
[5] "GDPpercapita"  "area_km2"          "populationdensity" "climate"            
EuropeWater$water_class <- factor(EuropeWater$water_class, levels=1:3, 
                                  labels=c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
EuropeWater$climate <- factor(EuropeWater$climate, levels=2:4, 
                              labels=c("Arid", "Warm temperate", "Snow"))
EuropeWater_tree <- rpart(EuropeWater$water_class ~ 
               population+GDPpercapita + area_km2 + populationdensity + 
               EuropeWater$climate, 
               data=EuropeWater, method=class)   
Error in as.character(x) : 
          cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'
```

and for the life of me, I can't figure out what the Error is about.

Comment: You may get a faster response if you provide a sample dataset.  You might want to take something out of the `datasets` package if that makes sense.

Comment: Shane is quite correct: if your more complex exercise fails, start with a simpler one as e.g. what `example(rpart)` does and go from there.

Answer (score 19):

Does this work?

```
EuropeWater_tree <- rpart(EuropeWater$water_class ~ 
 population+GDPpercapita + area_km2 + populationdensity + EuropeWater$climate, 
 data=EuropeWater, method="class")
```

I think you should quote method type.

When you use `class` instead of `"class"` then R is trying convert to character themself:

```
as.character(class)
Error in as.character(class) : 
    cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'
```

Because `class` is a function with type `builtin`:

```
typeof(class)
[1] "builtin"
```

Comment: Good catch! I'll amend my reply too.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by fixing the formula: remove the redundant `EuropeWater` as you already supply the `data=` argument:

```
res <- rpart(water_class ~ population + GDPpercapita + area_km2 + 
                           populationdensity + climate, 
             data=EuropeWater, method="class")
```

Also, make sure that all columns of your `data.frame` are of the appropriate type.  Maybe some of the data read from the csv file was mistakenly read as a factor?  A quick `summary(EuropeWater)` may reveal this.

Comment: I think that `str` could be better to quick view of `data.frame' content

Comment: Sure, or `sapply(EuropeWater, class)` to get class-by-column -- there are many options.