# How to Set up A Decision Tree

Tags: r, tree, classification, decision-tree

I am not sure of what I am doing  wrong? I am trying to grow a decision tree from my data.

```
CasinoTree <- rpart(Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + RateofReturn + 
                                 Default, data = CasinoTree, method = class)
```

***I suspect that I have incorrect information where it says `data = CasinoTree`

The message I get when I try this is.....

> Error in as.character(x) : 
>         cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'
>        In addition: Warning messages:
>      1: In model.matrix.default(attr(frame, "terms"), frame) :
>        the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
>     2: In model.matrix.default(attr(frame, "terms"), frame) :
>        problem with term 4 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned

My data is below.

```
    Competition FreeLiquor  RateofReturn    Default
1   Yes Yes High    No
2   Yes No  Low Yes
3   Yes Yes Low Yes
4   Yes Yes High    No
5   Yes No  Low Yes
6   Yes Yes Low No
7   Yes Yes High    No
8   Yes No  High    No
9   Yes No  Low Yes
10  Yes No  High    Yes
11  Yes No  Low Yes
12  Yes No  Low Yes
13  Yes No  Low Yes
14  No  No  Low Yes
15  No  No  High    No
16  No  No  Low Yes
17  No  No  High    No
18  No  Yes Low No
19  No  No  Low No
20  No  Yes High    No
21  No  No  High    No
22  No  No  High    No
23  No  No  Low No
24  No  Yes High    No
25  No  Yes Low Yes
```

I just tried this and received this error message

> rpart(Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + RateofReturn, data = casinotree, method = "class")
>   Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'casinotree' not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the rpart "Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character' " message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337018/what-does-the-rpart-error-in-as-characterx-cannot-coerce-type-builtin-to)

Comment: The first warning message says that `Default` is in the lhs and rhs of your formula... is this intended? Also you need to quote `"class"`

Comment: re, your edit... R is case sensitive. First you had `CasinoTree` and then `casinotree`

Comment: I am a real novice in this. Could you explain about the lhs and rhs? My intention is for  "Default" to be the Outcome. So the formula is 'Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + Rate of Return' . My latest edits include the following: rpart(Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + RateofReturn, data = casinotree, method = "class") Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'casinotree' not found. What should I do?

Comment: I added "class". Can you tell me if I list the correct information for data = ?

Comment: In your first model above the variable `Default` is on both the left hand side (lhs) and right hand side (rhs) of your formula - you corrected this in your edited model. However, you change your `data` from `CasinoTree` to `casinotree`.  If your data is named the former, this should work: `CasinoTree <- rpart(Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + RateofReturn , data = CasinoTree, method = "class")`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you were somehow confused with the naming of your data frame vs. the resulting rpart object (both called `CasinoTree` above) and with the response variable (which occurs also as one of the regressors). Possibly some data preparation is also not correct which is hard to tell from your problem description. If these problems are avoided (as below) everything works smoothly.

First, I read the data frame and call it `CasinoData`:

```
CasinoData <- read.table(textConnection('Competition FreeLiquor RateofReturn    Default
1   Yes Yes High    No
2   Yes No  Low Yes
3   Yes Yes Low Yes
4   Yes Yes High    No
5   Yes No  Low Yes
6   Yes Yes Low No
7   Yes Yes High    No
8   Yes No  High    No
9   Yes No  Low Yes
10  Yes No  High    Yes
11  Yes No  Low Yes
12  Yes No  Low Yes
13  Yes No  Low Yes
14  No  No  Low Yes
15  No  No  High    No
16  No  No  Low Yes
17  No  No  High    No
18  No  Yes Low No
19  No  No  Low No
20  No  Yes High    No
21  No  No  High    No
22  No  No  High    No
23  No  No  Low No
24  No  Yes High    No
25  No  Yes Low Yes'))
```

This seems to work well:

```
summary(CasinoData)

## Competition FreeLiquor RateofReturn Default 
## No :12      No :16     High:11      No :14  
## Yes:13      Yes: 9     Low :14      Yes:11
```

Then the `CasinoTree` can be created with `rpart()`:

```
library("rpart")
CasinoTree <- rpart(Default ~ Competition + FreeLiquor + RateofReturn,
  data = CasinoData)
```

which looks reasonable when printed:

```
CasinoTree

## n= 25 
## 
## node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
##       * denotes terminal node
## 
## 1) root 25 11 No (0.56000000 0.44000000)  
##   2) RateofReturn=High 11  1 No (0.90909091 0.09090909) *
##   3) RateofReturn=Low 14  4 Yes (0.28571429 0.71428571) *
```

or plotted (using the enhanced plotting of the `partykit` package):

```
plot(partykit::as.party(CasinoTree))
```

[image]